# Post-apocalyptic 80s movie set in New York. Everyone is hunting for the last fertile female

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for the title of a movie most likely made in the 80s -- I watched it in the 80s -- about a group of people looking for one of the last fertile women, or escorting one of the last fertile women to a place of safety. Film is set in post-apocalyptic New York. One of the characters, possibly a cyborg, has a map of New York memorized.

Answer (score 16):

Could this be *[2019, After the Fall of New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019,_After_the_Fall_of_New_York)*?

> It is set in 2019, after a nuclear apocalypse, and stars a mercenary
> out to rescue the last fertile woman on Earth.

Comment: For the record, this film is *awful*. Rather than watching it, I'd recommend you use the 1hr 36 minutes to [practice cooking the perfect omelette](https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/theperfectomelette_86680) or [organise your sock drawer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CW_9iwzhAjk)

Comment: Or watch [Children of Men(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_Men) instead, better yet read [the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Children_of_Men). I'd misremembered, in that it's male fertility (and it's set in the UK, and was written too late to have been to fit the title of this question - but it's good)

Comment: And the [film I stuffed up the link to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_Men), being a little shorter, would still allow time to make a couple of omelettes.

Comment: @ChrisH: Children of Men also depicts loss of *female* fertility.

Comment: @Make42 that's how I remembered it, but Wikipedia didn't say so.  I must admit it's years since I read it and I'm more into books than films, but it's got good reviews and I'd watch it.  I was reading a lot of detective stuff at the time, and picked up a PD James without looking at the back - a good surprise.  My local library has a copy, and I'm passing tomorrow, except it's out and overdue.

Comment: @ChrisH That or [*A Handmaid's Tale*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Handmaid%27s_Tale_(disambiguation)), book, film, opera, or currently running TV series.

Comment: My understanding about *Children of Men*, from a review I read of the movie, was that it was male infertility in the book and female infertility in the movie.

Comment: This movie is similar in some ways but I don't think this was it. The movie I remember was an American production with American actors. There were no 'ape-like mutants'. I don't think it had '2019' in the title, either.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman indeed, another one I re-read recently, but probably the best known

Comment: @MarkFoskey quite possibly, though having only read the book I recalled female infertility.  That could be me though, especially as wikipedia implies both male and female

Comment: @ChrisH I read the book a long time ago, but I vividly remember the male protagonist "forced" to take fertility tests each month to try to detect anything viable

Comment: @Lyzvaleska I can easily believe that - it was the female infertility in the title of this question that reminded me of the novel so may have biased my recollection.

Comment: @cannonfodder - Are you _absolutely sure_ this isn't the right movie? A character named Bronx, one of two men accompanying the main hero, does have the geography of New York memorised, and he also has a pincer-like prosthetic attachment where his right hand should be, making him a cyborg of sorts. Also, the so-called "ape-like mutants" described in the Wikipedia page look more like neanderthals than apes. I suggest you look up footage of the movie to confirm whether it genuinely conflicts with your memory or not, rather than quickly dismissing it on the basis of the Wiki page.